# 3.5mm to Bluetooth converter with support for both audio and microphone

Tags: audio, bluetooth

Okay, so I have an on-board sound card that I really like. I also have a high quality stereo Bluetooth headset with a built-in microphone that I really like. Now I want them to play together. And also, I want to stop fighting my Bluetooth drivers to get HSP and A2DP to work at the same time.

So here are my requirements:

- On the front of my computer are two 3.5mm sockets. A green one for audio output, a red one for microphone input. I want a dongle that would be able to connect to BOTH at the same time.
- The dongle should be able to pair with my headset, sending audio, and receiving microphone input. Obviously, the headset can't pair with two dongles at once, so it has to be a single dongle.
- Audio output should be high quality A2DP. This should not conflict with HSP/HFP for the microphone audio. It shouldn't be either/or, but work simultaneously.
- Should work while charging. I have a free USB port I can use, but obviously, I don't want to have to switch between plugging it in or out constantly.
- I sometimes watch videos, so lag under 200ms for audio would be needed. I know some systems have >500ms lag, so that's a big no.
- Optional: If possible, I'd like it to have Bluetooth 4 support.

I've looked around, but all I could find was either transmitters or receivers for A2DP with no support for a headset microphone. Some could even do both, but not at the same time.

Anything you could recommend?